# Programmatically export Azure SQL as DACPAC to Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, dacpac

I would like to perform a scheduled task of exporting an Azure SQL database as DACPAC to the Blob Storage. I would like to know can I do this. Web Job? Powershell script?

Answer (score 3):

We also can do this with WebJob. I create a demo with [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql -Pre](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql/0.51.0-prerelease) .Net SDK,and it works successfully for me.
More information about how to deploy webjob and create scheduled job please refer to the following documents.

[creating-and-deploying-microsoft-azure-webjobs](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28323.creating-and-deploying-microsoft-azure-webjobs.aspx)

[create-a-scheduled-webjob-using-a-cron-expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs#a-namecreatescheduledcronacreate-a-scheduled-webjob-using-a-cron-expression)

The following is my detail steps and sample code:

**Prerequisites:**

Registry an App in Azure AD and create service principle for it. More detail steps about how to registry app and get access token please refer to [document](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2016/10/21/using-the-azure-arm-rest-apin-get-access-token/).

**Steps:**

1.Create a C# console Application

2.Get accessToken by using registry App in Azure AD

```
public static string GetAccessToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string secretKey)
 {

    var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secretKey);
    var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
    var accessToken = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", clientCredential).Result;
    return accessToken.AccessToken;
  }
```

3.Create Azure sqlManagementClient object

```
  SqlManagementClient sqlManagementClient = new SqlManagementClient(new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, GetAccessToken(tenantId,clientId, secretKey)));
```

4.Use  sqlManagementClient.ImportExport.Export to export .dacpac file to azure storage

```
var export = sqlManagementClient.ImportExport.Export(resourceGroup, azureSqlServer, azureSqlDatabase,   
                    exportRequestParameters)
```

5. Go the the Bin/Debug path of the Application and Add **all** the contents in a .zip file.

[image]

6. Add the webjob from the Azure portal

[image]

[image]

7. Check the webjob log from the kudu tool

[image]

8. Check the backup file from the azure storage.

[image]

SDK info please refer to the Package.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Hyak.Common" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common.Dependencies" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql" version="0.51.0-prerelease" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.9" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="2.28.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.22" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish" version="1.0.12" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Demo code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var subscriptionId = "Your Subscription Id";
            var clientId = "Your Application Id";
            var tenantId = "tenant Id";
            var secretKey = "secretkey";
            var azureSqlDatabase = "Azure SQL Database Name";
            var resourceGroup = "Resource Group of Azure Sql ";
            var azureSqlServer = "Azure Sql Server";
            var adminLogin = "Azure SQL admin login";
            var adminPassword = "Azure SQL admin password";
            var storageKey = "Azure storage Account Key";
            var baseStorageUri = "Azure storage URi";//with container name endwith "/"
            var backName = azureSqlDatabase + "-" + $"{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyyMMddHHmm}" + ".bacpac";  //back up sql file name
            var backupUrl = baseStorageUri + backName;
            ImportExportOperationStatusResponse exportStatus = new ImportExportOperationStatusResponse();
            try
            {
                ExportRequestParameters exportRequestParameters = new ExportRequestParameters
                {
                    AdministratorLogin = adminLogin,
                    AdministratorLoginPassword = adminPassword,
                    StorageKey = storageKey,
                    StorageKeyType = "StorageAccessKey",
                    StorageUri = new Uri(backupUrl)
                };

                SqlManagementClient sqlManagementClient = new SqlManagementClient(new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, GetAccessToken(tenantId,clientId, secretKey)));
                var export = sqlManagementClient.ImportExport.Export(resourceGroup, azureSqlServer, azureSqlDatabase,   
                    exportRequestParameters); //do export operation

                while (exportStatus.Status != OperationStatus.Succeeded) // until operation successed
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60);
                    exportStatus = sqlManagementClient.ImportExport.GetImportExportOperationStatus(export.OperationStatusLink);  
                }

               Console.WriteLine($"Export DataBase {azureSqlDatabase} to Storage wxtom2 Succesfully");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

             //todo

            }
        }
```

Comment: ImportExport is not a method on the SqlManagementClient.  Am I missing something? I can't find these extensions anywhere...

Comment: As you mentioned that ImportExport  is removed in latest verson. I used the  version of  `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql` is **0.51.0-prerelease**

Answer (score 1):

Hi have you had a look at the following documentation which includes a PowerShell script and an Azure automation reference with sample script.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export-powershell